# Can get last message or listen to telegram channel with python-telegram -bot libarary?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

*I want make an bot for reading a last message of telegram channel thats meaning listening to Target channel*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with this bot, otherwise, you need to handle message with this [documentation](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.messagehandler.html).

In other way, with this other [package](https://python-telegram.readthedocs.io/en/0.14.0/telegram.html), you will be able to get history of chat.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).